# Python argparse versatility ability for true/false and string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following arguments parser using argparse in a python 2.7 script:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=scriptdesc)
parser.add_argument("-l", "--list", help="Show current running sesssions", dest="l_list", type=str, default=None)
```

I want to be able to run:

> ./script -l and ./script -l session_1

So that the script returns either all sessions or a single session without an extra parameter such as -s

However I can't find a way to do this in a single arg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack since it relies on accessing `sys.argv` outside of any `argparse` function but you can do something like:

```
import argparse
import sys


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
parser.add_argument("-l", "--list", help="Show current running sesssions", dest="l_list", nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.l_list == None:
    if '-l' in sys.argv or '--list' in sys.argv:
        print('display all')
else:
    print('display %s only' %args.l_list)
```

And you would obviously replace the print statements with your actual code.  This works by allowing 0 or 1 argument (using `nargs='?'`). This allows you to either pass an argument with `-l` or not.  This means that in the `args` namespace, `l_list` can be `None` (the default) if you call `-l` without an argument OR if you don't use `-l` at all.  Then later you can check if `-l` was called without an argument (if `l_list == None` and `-l` or `--list` is in `sys.argv`).

If I name this script `test.py` I get the following outputs when calling it from the command line.

```
$python test.py
$python test.py -l
display all
$python test.py -l session1
display session1 only
```

**EDIT**

I figured out an argparse only solution!! No relying on `sys.argv`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
parser.add_argument("-l", "--list", help="Show current running sesssions", dest="l_list", nargs='?', default=-1)
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.l_list == None:
    print('display all')
elif args.l_list != -1:
    print('display %s only' %args.l_list)
```

So it turns out that the `default` keyword in `.add_argument` only applies when the argument flag is not called *at all*. If the flag is used without anything following it, it will default to `None` regardless of what the `default` keyword is. So if we set the default to something that is not `None` and not an expected argument value (in this case I chose `-1`), then we can handle all three of your cases:

```
$ python test.py
$ python test.py -l
display all
$ python test.py -l session1
display session1 only
```

Comment: Thanks, this was similar to the workaround I had - I was interested if there was an argparse only solution - Thanks.

Comment: @user7186882 I figured out an argparse only way. Check out the edit

Comment: clever - I had tried the default parameter and saw it got set to None and that the default never got used - I think it's your combination of nargs and the default! Thanks!